# CORS error in developer tools in chrome for ionic 3

Tags: google-chrome, cors, ionic3

I am developing my app in ionic 3 and while hitting an API I am running into CORS error as below:

```
Failed to load http://myurl:3000/user/auth: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have tried below methods:
1)Chrome.exe --disable-web-security in chrome's installed folder.
2)Used the chrome's plugin (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/reviews?hl=en)

I am running in this issue only in chrome and I have reinstalled it too.I need to access native device feature and to debug it I need to read my console's.Also,the API are working fine when I build the APK and install it manually on my phone so there is no issue in my backend.Also,no cors issue in firefox but firefox is too complex to debug so I prefer chrome.
Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

CORS issue comes when you are hitting a site from different domain for more info 
checkout this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

You are getting this issue because you are hitting API from your local environment with different port. so to enable this you need to configure your local environment URL to access origin allowed at server side.

if you are using NodeJs for API then use this https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

for C# Api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api